# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet Android Studio

Tags: java, android, fragment

I need to remove a **QRCode** scan view when pressing on a button 
here is my code :

```
 public void back() {
    if (binding.vpPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
        binding.vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
else
    {
      scanQRcodeFragment = new ScanQRcodeFragment();
      scanQRcodeFragment.removeFragmentReader();
    }
}
```

The function to use :

```
public class ScanQRcodeFragment extends Fragment implements BarcodeReaderFragment.BarcodeReaderListener{
 public void removeFragmentReader() {
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragmentById = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (fragmentById != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentById);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}}
```

When I run the app, it crashes and I get this error :

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiateChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:2383)**

I found many questions with the same issue but no one resolves mine.

I need your help please.

Comment: Is there any `Fragment` attached into `R.id.container`?

Comment: Do you mean xml code ?

Comment: Yes. If you have added the fragment using `getSupportFragmentManager()` you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to remove that.

Comment: The code of removeFragmentReader() works before but when I call this same function in another class in the function back() as mentioned below, I get this  issue.

Comment: when you are calling from a different class, you are using a new reference that's why you can't remove it with this new reference. Please, check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove the fragment using a different object which hasn't instantiated it. `scanQRcodeFragment = new ScanQRcodeFragment();` Here you are instantiating a new object which isn't added, you need a reference of the added fragment to remove it.

Comment: This is correct. You should add them using a "TAG" and then find them by Tag (or keep a reference to the fragment if the scope allows it). I'd use a tag and then check if it's added via `findFragmentByTag("your tag")

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating a new instance of the fragment before removing it; that doesn't make sense.

Your code should be (pseudo-code) more like:

```
public void back() {
    if (binding.vpPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
        binding.vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
else
    {
      // must remove the Fragment
      Fragment = f = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(QR_CODE_FRAGMENT_TAG);
      if (f != null && f.isAttached()) {
           fragmentManager
              .beginTransaction()
              .remove(f)
              .commit();
       } else {
           // Fragment is not attached, nothing to do here, you can remove this code.
       }
    }
}
```

Note:
Keep in mind that `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()` is a dangerous operation. Depending what you do, your state (aka: the transaction) *may be lost* if the context goes away before the state is updated and the activity has saved its state already.

What you probably want is `commitNow()` because this is not a back stack operation (the downside of commitNow is that you cannot add the transaction to the backstack to *pop it* later), which is an expected side-effect, but not often known by some developers :)